# Identify this insect in Texas

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Please help identify the insect in the attached picture.  It was found in the Dallas/Fort Worth area in Texas, today, April 18 2023.  It is about 0.25 inches long.

Update in response to comment:  It was found in the backyard of my house, in shallow soil that I had recently been digging in and re-grading.  The white background in the picture is a potting soil bag I flicked it onto to get a better look.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thorax is all wrong for a juvenile cockroach as others have suggested. (A cockroach would have an [enlarged prothorax covering the head, as well as plate-like meso-and meto-thoraxes](https://lanwebs.lander.edu/faculty/rsfox/invertebrates/periplaneta.html)). Also, the antennae are too short.

Instead...

Based on the size, location (soil), and body shape (especially indent at base of [pornotum](https://www.britannica.com/animal/beetle/Form-and-function), apparent split between [elytra](https://www.britannica.com/animal/beetle/Form-and-function) seen at the right of your image, and the *short* [filliform](https://www.amentsoc.org/insects/fact-files/antennae.html) antennae), it is much more likely this is some species of [**ground beetle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_beetle) (Carabidae).

- According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_beetle), "All carabids...have a groove on their fore leg tibiae bearing a comb of hairs used for cleaning their antennae." However, your image does not provide enough clarity to effectively check (though perhaps th right leg showing a spur associated with this groove?).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_beetle):

> more than 40,000 species worldwide, around 2,000 of which are found in North America and 2,700 in Europe.[3] As of 2015, it is one of the 10 most species-rich animal families

As such, I do not intend to try to identify this to species.

- [Here](https://catalog.extension.oregonstate.edu/sites/catalog/files/project/pdf/em9301.pdf) is a key to Oregon species to demonstrate variability in morphology as well as to emphasize structures to emphasize when trying to ID to species level.

Although I do not believe this to be your species, I wanted to include an image of an example specimen for reference:

[image]

<sup>Amber-colored Ground Beetle - *Platynus brunneomarginatus*. Photo  credit: [Jim Moore](https://bugguide.net/user/view/38542) (2018); [Bugguide.net](https://bugguide.net/node/view/1489476)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @theforestecologist, that is great.  Eliminating roach as a possibility helps a lot.

Comment: Another possible difficulty with this specimen is the teneral appearance (I find it possible that the animal had only recently emerged from its pupa); the same animal seen a few hours (or more) later might be considerably darker.